# Multiple forms with one submit() method by Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a few forms. Every of them have the same logic (validation, sending...) so, I want to create one method to control actions on my forms. For now my code is redundancy, because I have the same methods `onSubmit()` on every **.vue** file.

my HTML:

```
<div id="app">
    <myform-one></myform-one>
    <myform-two></myform-two>
</div>
```

my JavaScript (**main.js** - entry file in webpack):

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Myform1 from './myform1.vue';
import Myform2 from './myform2.vue';

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        myformOne: Myform1,
        myformTwo: Myform2
    }
});
```

and VUE components files:

**myform1.vue**:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
            <input type="text" v-model="fields.fname11" />
            <input type="text" v-model="fields.fname12" />
            <button type="submit">submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    let formfields = {
        fname11: '',
        fname12: ''
    };

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                fields: formfields
            }
        },

        methods: {
            onSubmit() {
                // code responsible for reading, validating and sending data here
                // ...
                console.log(this.fields);
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

and **myform2.vue**:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
            <input type="text" v-model="fields.fname21" />
            <input type="text" v-model="fields.fname22" />
            <input type="text" v-model="fields.fname23" />
            <button type="submit">submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    let formfields = {
        fname21: '',
        fname22: '',
        fname23: '',
    };

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                fields: formfields
            }
        },

        methods: {
            onSubmit() {
                // code responsible for reading, validating and sending data here
                // ...
                console.log(this.fields);
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

How can I create and use one, common method `submitForm()`? And where its code should be (good practice)?

Comment: You should sue mixins https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

Comment: You can use `vuex` actions.

Answer (score 1):

Vue3 (with Quasar for me but I'm sure it would work for any framework):

Say you have a parent which contains a number of forms `<Forms />`:

First create a composable function like so `useForms.js`:

```
import { ref } from 'vue'

const forms = ref([])

export function useForms(){
  
  const checkForms = () => {
    forms.value.forEach((form) => form.validate()
  }  

  const addFormToFormsArray = (form) => {
    forms.value.push(form)
  }

  return { forms, addFormToFormsArray, checkForms }
}
```

Then import it into `<Forms />`:

```
<template>
  <Form />
  <Form />
  <Form />
  <button @click="checkForms">Check Form</button>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useForms } from '../useForms';

const { checkForms } = useForms()
</script>
```

Finally, inside the `<Form />`:

```
<template>
  <form ref="form">
    .../stuff
  </form>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import { useForms } from '../useForms';

const form = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
  addFormToFormsArray(form.value)
})

const { checkForms, addFormToFormsArray } = useForms()
</script>
```

When performing the check function in the parent, it should go through each form and check for any issues.

Answer (score 0):

> There are some options. My favorite is creating a mixin [vue docs mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)

```
export const form_functionality = {
  methods: {
     on_submit() {
      //logic of submit
     },
     //here we can have other reusable methods
  }
}
```

Then in your components use that mixin as follow:

```
import { form_functionality } from 'path_of_mixin'
export default {
  mixins: [form_functionality]
}
```

In the end, what mixins has (created, methods, data etc) will be merged to the component
which uses that mixin.

So, practically you can access the mixin method like `this.on_submit()`

Comment: looks very well, but how can I inject my form fields data (`formfields` variable)?

Comment: I can't understand fully the case, but you can send the formfields to submit method. Like `this.on_submit(this.formFields)`

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate file which contains the logic:

```
// submitForm.js
export default function (fields) {
   // code responsible for reading, validating and sending data here
   // ...
}
```

Then use that logic inside the components

```
import submitForm from "../services/submitForm.js"
...
methods: {
  onSubmit() {
    submitForm(this.fields)
  }
}
```